# Moving cvs repository to a new machine

Tags: cvs

We have a CVS repository on machine 'A'. Want to copy a specific directory to machine 'B's CVS with all the history from 'A'. The problem is I can only access CVS on machine 'A' using Eclipse only (dont have access using Unix). Is it possible to do that using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You could probably script an automatic checkout from A and commit to B based on `cvs log` output but you'd still lose date and author information and reinstating tags and branches will probably get tricky, too.

You should better find someone with file-level access to the two repositories as in that case it's a simple copy operation. No additional work required.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, this is what I thought. I will wait for any other answer for a day and if cant get a better one then will choose this one as best answer.